# Configure IIS for upload multiple website under same domain

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, iis-7, asp-classic

I have classic asp project uploaded in the IIS 7 with ApplicationPool set to .Net framework 2.0.Now I have develop admin site for that but its in the asp.net 3.5.So I want to insert this application inside this classic asp project which is deployed.
i.e.

old classic asp have url

```
http://192.168.1.159:8888/profile/
```

and now my admin site will reflect to

```
http://192.168.1.159:8888/profile/admin/
```

but I am getting some error when I try to look in the browser and its failed to load.
How can I configure this or what setting I have to do in IIS 7 so that this will work fine ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to configure your `/admin` folder as a new application.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Expand your computer node
3. Expand the sites node
4. Expand the site you want this new application under
5. Right click on the `/admin` folder
6. Select convert to application
7. Fill in the alias box and check the physical path box
8. Click OK and you're done.

See [here](https://support.gearhost.com/KB/a460/add-virtual-directory-as-application-in-iis-7.aspx) for a picture of the dialog that opens after step 6.